# What is the best way to edit google docs using the API?

Tags: google-docs-api

I'd like to be able to edit any kind of Google docs using the API from Google App Engine.
My goal is to lose as little information as possible when editing the document. The edits are fairly simple like replacing some words.

- Document

To edit them, I'm doing an export in HTML and importing it again. But we are loosing some information like notes. There is also an issue with the title, the size before each title increase at every new update, so I have to reset some css. Is there is a better way of editing docs ?

- Spreadsheet

There is the spreadsheet API, so I think I'm covered.

- Presentation

I did not find a format that I could export and import again. The only one seems to be powerpoint. But powerpoint files cannot be easily edited.

- Drawing

I did not find a format that can be both exported and imported. I tried with SVG, but svg cannot be imported back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Document**

PDF offers you the best fidelity in and out of Google Docs, without the hassle of proprietary or complicated formats like MS Word files.

**Spreadsheet**

Only proprietary or complicated formats guarantee fidelity here of things like cell color.  The Spreadsheets API only allows data to be updated, but not formatting.

**Presentation**

You are correct, PPTX is the only format that can go both in and out of Google Presentations.

**Drawing**

You are correct, there is no import format that can go both in and out of Google Drawings.

Comment: I tried doing it with PDF, the issue is PDF does not do the auto-reflow, so if the string I'm changing in a text is longer or shorter, it's breaking the page.

Comment: FWIW Vic, I'm sure we won't be the first to tell you that this is a critical limitation of Docs.  A ton of extremely useful stuff simply cannot be done in Docs because of this.

Comment: Thanks, Jan.  I'll consider this an important feature request.